# Problem with Electron , Creating screenshot application

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, screenshot, chromium

I'm creating a Tray application using electron to take screenshots when I press a given shortcut. As of right now, I'm able to get a print when I click my test button on the window I created, but when I remove the window from the code and try to call the print method using a shortcut, I get the following error:

> "Cannot read property 'getSources' of undefined"

Do you guys know how to help me ?

```
const {app,desktopCapturer, BrowserWindow, Menu , Tray, 
globalShortcut} = require('electron');


function fullscreenScreenshot(callback, imageFormat) {
var _this = this;
this.callback = callback;
imageFormat = imageFormat || 'image/jpeg';

this.handleStream = (stream) => {
    // Create hidden video tag
    var video = document.createElement('video');
    video.style.cssText = 'position:absolute;top:-10000px;left:-10000px;';

    // Event connected to stream
    video.onloadedmetadata = function () {
        // Set video ORIGINAL height (screenshot)
        video.style.height = this.videoHeight + 'px'; // videoHeight
        video.style.width = this.videoWidth + 'px'; // videoWidth

        video.play();

        // Create canvas
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = this.videoWidth;
        canvas.height = this.videoHeight;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        // Draw video on canvas
        ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        if (_this.callback) {
            // Save screenshot to base64
            _this.callback(canvas.toDataURL(imageFormat));
        } else {
            console.log('Need callback!');
        }

        // Remove hidden video tag
        video.remove();
        try {
            // Destroy connect to stream
            stream.getTracks()[0].stop();
        } catch (e) {}
    }

    video.srcObject = stream;
    document.body.appendChild(video);
};

this.handleError = function(e) {
    console.log(e);
};

desktopCapturer.getSources({ types: ['window', 'screen'] }).then(async sources => {
    console.log(sources);
    isTime = false;

    for (const source of sources) {
        // Filter: main screen
        if ((source.name === "Entire screen") || (source.name === "Screen 1")) {
            try{
                const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                    audio: false,
                    video: {
                        mandatory: {
                            chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
                            chromeMediaSourceId: source.id,
                            minWidth: 1280,
                            maxWidth: 4000,
                            minHeight: 720,
                            maxHeight: 4000
                        }
                    }
                });

                _this.handleStream(stream);
            } catch (e) {
                _this.handleError(e);
            }
        }
    }
});
}

function createWindow () {
let win = new BrowserWindow({
width: 720,
height: 480,
webPreferences: {
    nodeIntegration: true
}
})

win.loadFile('index.html');
win.webContents.openDevTools();
tray = new Tray('./hp-logo.png')
const contextMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([
{ label: 'Take Screenshot', type: 'radio', checked: true },
{ label: 'Settings', type: 'radio'}
])
tray.setContextMenu(contextMenu);
globalShortcut.register('Alt+q' , () => { fullscreenScreenshot( () => console.log('callback'),'image/jpeg'  )})
}

app.on('ready', createWindow);
```

Comment: Welcome.  Please read [ask].  Your title is not useful.  It should describe the error or problem.  Additionally, errors in the console info is very useful: it usually includes the file and line number that is throwing the issue.  Which line in your code is throwing this notice?  Lastly, format your code.  It'll make your life easier, as well as make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: What do you mean by "remove the window from my code"?

Comment: Right now I'm creating a window for the apllication, but in the end the application should not have a window, just an icon on the windows bar